# Возможно ли в ВК перейти по ссылке с заготовленным текстом сообщения?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

На сайте хочу сделать подписку на объявления по различным параметрам:город, категория и т.д.
Далее, бот ВК будет рассылать подходящие объявления в ЛС.

На данный момент, у всех вижу такую схему : по ссылке с сайта зашел к боту в ЛС, написал "привет" и покликакал по подсказкам (выбрал город, категорию и т.д), после чего бот отправляет данные на сервер с параметрами твоей подписки.

А я хочу, чтобы, как только человек перешел к боту, в поле ввода текста сразу добавился текст с уже заготовленными параметрами с сайта, без лишних телодвижений. Такое возможно ? Например, может ВК поддерживает какие-то GET-параметры, например https://vk.com/write-180421111`&text=blabla`

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать ref. Текст в сообщение он не подставит, но пользователя вы отследить сможете. 
https://vk.com/dev/bizmessages_doc?f=2.6.%20%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8%20vk.me